# Is it safe to reuse cuMemAlloc memory after I call cuCtxDestroy?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, gpu

Is it safe to use a [cuMemAlloc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1gb82d2a09844a58dd9e744dc31e8aa467) memory allocation after [cuCtxDestroy](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g27a365aebb0eb548166309f58a1e8b8e) has been called?

E.g.

```
cuCtxCreate()
void *d_buffer;
cuMemAlloc(d_buffer, ....);
cuCtxDestroy();

// In another place but same thread
cuCtxCreate();
kernel_call<<<..>>>(d_buffer); // Use the device allocation previously created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, the allocation is part of the [context](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#context).

when you destroy the context, you also destroy any resources associated with it, including memory allocations.

even without your context destruction, if you attempt to use a `CUdeviceptr` created (i.e. allocated) under another context, when that other context is not current, you should get an "invalid device pointer" error (or a kernel runtime error, if you pass it to a kernel, such as "illegal access")

also note that you are mixing driver API usage here, with runtime API syntax (`<<<..>>>`) so I'm not suggesting that what you wrote is actually sane in any particular situation, just trying to respond to your question.